# Factorial function calling itself

Tags: javascript, function

I came across this function which works fine for the purpose but I can't get why factorial can be called in a factorial() function. Can someone explain to me.

```
function factorial(n) {
  if(n ==0) {
    return 1;
  }else{
    return factorial(n-1) *n;
  }
}
console.log(factorial(8));
//Logs 40320
```

Comment: It is called recursion

Comment: "*why factorial can be referred in a factorial().*" - because it is a function declared in scope.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

please read this code it's work.

```js
 function factorialize(num) {
  // Step 1. Create a variable result to store num
  var result = num;
   
  // If num = 0 OR num = 1, the factorial will return 1
  if (num === 0 || num === 1) 
    return 1; 
 
  // Step 2. Create the WHILE loop 
  while (num > 1) { 
    num--; // decrementation by 1 at each iteration
    result = result * num; // or result *= num; 
    /* 
                    num           num--      var result      result *= num         
    1st iteration:   5             4            5             20 = 5 * 4      
    2nd iteration:   4             3           20             60 = 20 * 3
    3rd iteration:   3             2           60            120 = 60 * 2
    4th iteration:   2             1          120            120 = 120 * 1
    5th iteration:   1             0          120
    End of the WHILE loop 
    */
  }
     
  // Step 3. Return the factorial of the provided integer
  return result; // 120
}
console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Comment: The asker isn't asking how to make a factorial function, they're asking how the recursive function they posted works

Answer (score 0):

It's called recursion. What's recursion?

> Recursion is simply when a function calls itself.

You can find out more of it in JavaScript [here](https://codeburst.io/learn-and-understand-recursion-in-javascript-b588218e87ea)

Answer (score -1):

This is a **Software Engineering (Data Structure and Algorithms)** concept called recursion.

Recursion is the programming concept where a function calls itself. In the case of the factorial function, from observation, for all integers n greater than 1, `factorial(n) = n * factorial(n-1)`. E. g. `factorial(5) = 5 * factorial(4)`
this means, in the implementation, the function can call itself with `(n-1)` and multiply the result by `n`.

You can read more from [here](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/recursion/whatisrecursion/section1/).

Recursion has [advantages and disadvantages](http://www.tutorialdost.com/C-Programming-Tutorial/15-C-Recursion.aspx).